# Selenium webdriver - Unable to locate element,xpath,error

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am testing localization. I am running the same URL with other countries in my data provider.

The HTML I am looking for is:

```
<a class="learn-more linkable" data-url="/speakers/minijambox">En savoir plus</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
String storeXpath2="//a[contains(@href,'"+url2+"')]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(storeXpath2)).click();
System.out.println("Learn more link of Mini");
```

url I am trying to execute: `/speakers/minijambox`

Error I am getting unable to find xpath, element or method.

Comment: Can you provide a Stack trace of errors being thrown?  Also, the html snippet of the <a> tag you are trying to access might help too

Comment: stack Trace : https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/register-or-reset?affId=18&callback=http%3a%2f%2fsqa.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2fauthenticate%3fforceLogin%3d6504%252cTaynUgAAAABNrKdSAAAAAA%253d%253d%257c72c267c38c9db07ca072e26b9f534bffdbfabf94b9f70b4feded48c0fad8576d&email=drastogi%40jawbone.com&nonce=TaynUgAAAAAy9ADL7djNYg%3d%3d&authCode=CFiIrD1%2fNhbXfJ1WxMxnlJfdg37nzdK8HYyTmarQQp0O%2b6vV%2fCjl6xLAPrtwhq7sBRNYv6OCULzhK%2f%2fyZfLlmip0C4waB8ph7RtEPicfrLogecm6EJDkpSTv3pGEjba2N4RrE7ThCGmSPPlXmK868GGlkgoPLCtb01E9E8cMSo4%3d

Comment: HTML tag : <a class="learn-more linkable" data-url="/speakers/minijambox">En savoir plus</a>

Comment: This is a localization test case. I am running the same url with other countries in my data provider.

Comment: @jbyogi, I've edited your question to put the HTML tag and the information about it being a localization test in the question body. Could you please edit the question to include the stack trace? Your link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML tag you are trying to match has a `class` attribute and a `data-url` attribute but not an `href` attribute.  Either you mistyped the HTML tag in your question or you need to change the definition of `storeXpath2` to something like this:

```
String storeXpath2="//a[contains(@data-url,'"+url2+"')]";
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Your suggested solution didn't work. I used the same definition for different tag:  String storeXpath="//a[contains(@href,'"+url+"')]";
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(storeXpath)).click();
  System.out.println("buy now for Mini"); and this seems to work fine.

Comment: Is it possible the same definition worked for a different tag because the different tag had an `href` attribute?

Comment: It has the same tag as I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: But the tag you mentioned in the post did not have an `href` attribute.  Quote: 'HTML tag : <a class="learn-more linkable" data-url="/speakers/minijambox">En savoir plus</a>'.  What am I missing?

Comment: yeah. But code does not work with data-url attribute.href works with storeXpath -url but it does not when i pass storexpath2-url2

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
String xpath = //li[@class="minijambox linkable"]/a[@href="/speakers/minijambox"]
```

Comment: does not seem to work.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I checked for US and Spain locale, I do see the DOM hierarchy that you mention.  I also verified with FirePath in Firebug and the xpath is identified.  

Another thing that I can think of is, you are trying to access the element before the page loads.  A small wait might do the trick